# Getting the ID of from table row I just inserted

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have free textboxes TP_ID, Deny, Level

When i enter The values for Deny and Level and i click submit they are stored into the Database and TP_ID is Auto_Increment.

```
<form name="Permit" id="Permit" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="TPID" value=""> <br>
        <input type="text" name="Permit_or_Deny" value=""> <br>
        <input type="text" name="Level" value=""> <br>


        <p>input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="save" /></p>

     </form>
<?php
    if( (isset($_POST['Permit_or_Deny'])) || (isset($_POST['Level']))|| (isset($_POST['TPID'])) ) 
        {

        $Permit_or_Deny = $_POST['Permit_or_Deny'];
        $Level= $_POST['Level'];
        $TPID= $_POST['TPID'];
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "INSERT INTO tp_newedit (TP_ID, Permit_or_Deny, Level) 
        VALUES ('".$TPID."','".$Permit_or_Deny."','".$Level."');";
        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $db->query();
        echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
        } else

    ?>
```

Is there any way to retrieve the last created ID and display it in the textbox ?

Comment: are you talking about this $db->insertid();?

Comment: Note that in this instance, the 'stop/starts' ("./.") are unnecessary.

Comment: If you are using a `DBO`, why not parametrise query? Why keep yourself prone to injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work 
`$id = $db->insert_id;`

assuming it's using mysqli

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$db->insertid()
```

See:
http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JDatabase::insertid
for more info.

Comment: Faulty source. It's not insertid(), but insert_id()

Comment: Where did you find that OP is using Joomla?

Comment: $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

Comment: Thanks Guys once ive used  $db->insertid(); how do I Store it into a different table ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Source:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. This returns the last inserted id for a given session.

Here is an example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO cities VALUES (NULL, 'Banglore','India',42789);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM cities;
+----+------------+---------+------------+
| id | city       | country | population |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
|  5 | Paris      | France  |   11836970 |
|  6 | Nantes     | France  |     283025 |
|  7 | London     | UK      |    7556900 |
|  8 | Manchester | UK      |     464200 |
|  9 | Hull       | UK      |     258700 |
| 11 | Banglore   | India   |      42789 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|               11 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but once ive gotten  the Last Id how do I insert it into another table?